# automatic transformation of file extension

Tags: git

i got stuck in a confusion. there is a file which when downloaded the name was shown as "git-completion.bash" with the file-type extension name `.txt` in the Save-As option prior to the beginning of downloading. that means the full name with extension is `git-completion.bash.txt`.
but when I viewed this file in my directory after downloading, the name was "git-completion" and the file-type extension is `.bash` , and so the full name with extension is "git-completion.bash".
so is there something which happened under the hood?

Comment: What operating system are you running on, and what tool were you using to view?

Comment: If this is Windows and you add an extension in the save file dialog, Windows won’t add another extension. So if the textbox contained `git-completion.bash` instead of `git-completion.bash.txt`, it worked fine.

Comment: i haven't added anything from my side, everything was pre-filled when the save file dialog box pops out and all i did is just pressed teh enter button. if window wont add another extension then why the dialog box was pre-filled like that with another extension

Comment: @Andrew what tool were you using?

Comment: @VonC i dont know what specific you mean by "tool". i am working on windows7, and using firefox, and the page was downloaded from a site

Comment: @Andrew when you select "save as", in which application are you? Firefox?

Comment: @VonC Yeah Firefox

Answer (score 1):

As [mentioned here](https://www.thesitewizard.com/faqs/save-without-txt-extension-notepad.shtml), by [Christopher Heng](https://twitter.com/thefreecountry):

> Notepad, up to the current version, has the practice of adding a "`.txt`" extension to your files even when you don't specify it.
>   So if you give your file a name of "`blahblahblah.html`", Notepad will change the name to "`blahblahblah.html.txt`" without informing you.

With Firefox, that means the **[`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)** of the page "git-completion.bash" was not set or set to `text/plain`. See [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/929660).

> Compounding this problem is Windows Explorer's policy of not telling you the full filename of your files. Hence if you use Explorer to check the file, it will only show "`blahblahblah.html`".
>
> If you have already saved your file, the best way to solve this is to:
>
> - first **force Explorer to always show you the file extension**, and
> - then change the filename to the correct one.
>
> This is good practice anyway, since always being able to see the full filename probably improves your system's security — you'll be less likely to be tricked by all those scams asking you to click a file that appears to be a picture but is actually a program.
>
> On Windows Vista and above, lick the Start menu, and type "`folder options`" (without the quotes), and click the "`Folder Options`" line that appears near the top of the Start menu.
>   Click the "`View`" tab in the dialog box that appears.
>   Look for a setting "`Hide file extensions for known file types`" and uncheck the box beside it to disable it.
>   Then click the "`OK`" button at the bottom of the dialog box.

---

The OP mentions [git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash), which when saved with Firefox, gives a `.txt` file.
The "`Content-Type`" for that file seems to be "`text/plain`".

This is a regression mentioned in [FireFox bug 511624](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=511624)

Try setting the content type with [Force Content-Type](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/force-content-type/) plugin

Comment: i wanna mention few points:

1- i already forced Explorer to always show the file extension

2- there is no role of notepad here as not needed to open a text editor, nor i found any explicit or implicit addition of `.txt` extension. 

3- the file which i mentioned about was meant to behave like double extension as it was behaving in udacity tutorial. the workspace is also set up same as in tutotrial. its just that in tutorial the file with double extension is downloaded & behaving like the double extension with no changes.
And so the extra .txt intention was intentionally programmed

Comment: @Andrew "there is no role of notepad here as not needed to open a text editor," I did not know because you didn't mention anything in your quesiton. You did not mention udacity tutorial as well. Do you have a link for me to follow and try to reproduce your case?

Comment: Oops my bad! yeah the link is-->  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
there is no download button in that page. you have to download the whole page by "save page as" option